# Derivative of $ 4e^{xy ^ {y}} $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Here's what I've got so far: for $ y $ as some function of x:

$$ f(x) =4e^{(xy) ^ {y}} \\
 f'(x) = 4e^{(xy) ^ {y}} \cdot \frac {d}{dx} [(xy)^{y}] \cdot\frac{d}{dx} [y]\\
 \implies 4e^{(xy) ^ {y}}  \left(y + x\frac{dy}{dx}\right) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}. $$

Comment: What is $y$? Is it a constant or some function of $x$?

Comment: A function of $ x $. I am really messing it up.

Comment: You are going wrong when you take the derivative of $(xy)^y$, which is not $(y+xy')$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
f&=4e^{(xy)^y}\\
\implies f'&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[4e^{{(xy)}^y}\right]\\
&=4e^{{(xy)}^y}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(xy)^y\\
&=4e^{{(xy)}^y}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{y\ln(xy)}\right]\\
&=4e^{{(xy)}^y}\cdot e^{y\ln(xy)}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left[y\ln(xy)\right]\\
&=4e^{{(xy)}^y}\cdot(xy)^y\cdot\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\ln(xy)+\frac{y}{xy}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(xy)\right]\\
&=4e^{{(xy)}^y}\cdot(xy)^y\cdot\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\ln(xy)+\frac1x\cdot\left(y+x\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\right]\\
\implies f'&=4e^{{(xy)}^y}\cdot(xy)^y\cdot\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\ln(xy)+\frac yx+\frac{dy}{dx}\right]\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

I like to define simple functions and define the $f(x)$ as a composition of these simple functions.  Then I don't get lost when applying the chain rule.

let $u = xy\\
v = u^y = e^{y\ln u}$

$f(x) = 4e^v\\
f' = 4e^v v'\\
v' = u^y(y'\ln u + \frac {y}{u}u')\\
u' = y + xy'$

$f'= 4e^{(xy)^y}(xy)^y(y'(\ln x + \ln y) + \frac {y}{x}+ y')$

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to figure out the derivative of $h(x)=x^x$. We have
$$\ln h = x\ln x$$
$$\frac {h'}h = 1+\ln x$$
$$\implies h' = (1+\ln x)x^x$$
Using the chain rule, it follows that $(y^y)' = y'y^y(1+\ln y)$. Further, noting that for any $g(x)$ the derivative of $e^g$ is $g'e^g$, we have
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^y = \frac{d}{dx}e^{y\ln x} = \left(\frac y x+y'\ln x\right)x^y$$ 
Finally,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(4e^{(xy)^y}\right) = 4 \left(\frac{d}{dx}x^yy^y\right)e^{(xy)^y}$$
$$ = 4\left(\left(\frac y x+y'\ln x\right)x^yy^y+x^yy^yy'(1+\ln y)\right)e^{(xy)^y}$$
$$= 4\left(\frac y x+y'(1+\ln x+\ln y) \right)(xy)^ye^{(xy)^y}$$