# Derivative of Repeated Exponent

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponentiation

Given $y=e^{(xy)^y}$, find $\frac {dy}{dx}$.

This problem originated from a misunderstanding of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322499/derivative-of-4exy-y). I solved the problem in this post first, before I realized my solution was incorrect. However, I've decided to upload the problem and solution anyway as I imagine someone can find some use from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can solve this problem using a combination of implicit and logarithmic differentiation:
$$y=4e^{(xy)^y}$$
$$\ln{\frac y4}=(xy)^y$$
$$\ln{\left(\ln \frac y4\right)}=y\ln{(xy)}$$
Taking the derivative of both sides:
$$\frac 1{\ln \frac y4}\left(\frac{\frac{y'}4}{\frac y4}\right)=y\left(\frac{y+xy'}{xy}\right)+y'\ln{(xy)}$$
$$\frac{y'}{y\ln{\left(\frac y4\right)}}=\frac yx+y'+y'\ln{(xy)}$$
$$xy'=y^2\ln \frac y4+xyy'\ln \frac y4+xyy'\left(\ln \frac y4\right)\ln{(xy)}$$
$$y'=\frac{y^2\ln \frac y4}{x-xy\ln \frac y4-xy\left(\ln \frac y4\right)\ln {(xy)}}$$
Not beautiful, but correct.

I hope someone can learn something from this interesting use of repeated logarithms to differentiate functions, or just enjoy an unusual but cool derivative.